# logback parsing error in spring boot 1.4

Tags: spring-boot, logback

after updating my program to spring boot 1.4 the logs in /var/log/messages started to be printed as

```
%PARSER_ERROR[wEx]%PARSER_ERROR[clr] %PARSER_ERROR[clr] %PARSER_ERROR[clr] %PARSER_ERROR[clr] %PARSER_ERROR[clr] %PARSER_ERROR[clr] %PARSER_ERROR[clr]
```

the program is installed as a systemd service using

```
 <configuration>
   <executable>true</executable>
 </configuration>
```

how can i debug the problem to check what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be something in the server , after a complete server restart it worked out , couldn't tell what was the problem